# How to create an Android M preview project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

I've installed the Android M preview SDK and am trying to create a project using it (to experiment with the new permissions model).

When I create a new project using Android Studio it presents Android M as a choice for the minimum SDK:

[image]

However when I try and build the project it says

```
failed to find target android-23 install missing platforms.
```

But I've already installed the M platform otherwise how did it offer it as a choice when I created the project? 
Anyway if I click on the "install missing platforms" linkI get a licence agreement for SDK platform 23 dialog, which when I accept and proceed to 
the download again it says:

```
"Ignoring unknown package filter 'android-23'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter."
```

Here's  the SDK manager:[image]

Comment: Solved - I only updated to the latest AS update last week, but to use M you have to update yet again to an even newer AS beta build.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it